# Задать лимиты для 3D пространства в matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Как указать фиксированное пространство по x, y и z? Когда я работал с двумерными графиками, эту задачу я решал с помощью:

```py
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-450, 450), ylim=(-450, 450))
```

По моей логике, я сделал вывод, что могу просто добавить аргумент `zlim`, но к сожалению, так не работает.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4913306/5741205

Comment: @MaxU, спасибо большое